# Move a website over to CMS

Tags: css, xhtml, content-management-system

I have a static website that has been built by converting psd to xhtml/css and includes a little PHP. This is the extent to which I design websites at the current time.

My client has now informed me on whether it would be a difficult process to incorporate a CMS into the website. Now I know what a CMS is and I know the common opensource systems like Drupal, Wordpress and Joomla.

My first question is :-

- Would I be incorporating one of these CMS's into my website or the website into a CMS?

and

- Is it a long process to get a CMS integrated?

Comment: This is a very complex issue that is outside of the scope of StackOverflow questions.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer. An expert in one of those CMS's could probably do it quickly, but to learn one well enough to edit the source code to get your site looking exactly as it does now is not trivial

Comment: The complexity of your project will depend on whether you are a professional software developer or a web programmer. If your knowledge of software products is limited to converting psd to xhtml/css with little php. You are in for a lot of hair-pulling trying to get a CMS running. So be prepared for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would I be incorporating one of these CMS's into my website or the website into a CMS?

That wholly depends on how you and your client want to manage the website. If the client only wants to be able to "blog" then it's easier to add the CMS to your website for specific pages that the client wants to manage.

On the other hand, if the client wants to manage the entire site via CMS, then you would be building your site in the CMS of your choosing.

> Is it a long process to get a CMS integrated?

It depends on your familiarity with CMS's. I can speak on wordpress, as it's the one I'm most familiar with--once you've built/selected/customized a theme that matches your original website (or the look for your new site), adding content is fairly easy. In my opinion, the biggest time spent is in customizing the theme.

Edit to add:

If time was the consideration, my approach would be to either buy a theme online that the client agrees to, or subcontract out the Wordpress theme design to someone who has a lot of experience building custom themes. The latter option is not "cheap" by anymeans, but there are a number of freelance designers who do design wordpress themes.

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much rebuild from the ground up. You design the way you want it to look then upload content through a "more user-friendly" interface.

Personally, I found it a pain to use Drupal, and Joomla is just a bag of bolts to me. I'm in the process of developing a custom CMS for a client. It's my first one, but it's going pretty smoothly.

If the end user is pretty skillful one of those systems might not be a big deal. Otherwise, expect to give this client a lot of attention.

Wordpress is pretty nice, I must say. I wouldn't use it for an entire site (though many do), but I will use it for my blog once I get the theme setup (there's a learning curve there. you have to familiarize yourself with their system).

So, if your client doesn't want to edit much, I would just build a secure page for them to edit the wording, make a 'New Article' or new page, which shouldn't be a stretch if your site is already in PHP and you can get around pretty well.

Good Luck!